# Add button to Email in Outlook to process information

Tags: c#, email, outlook, exchange-server

I wrote a Web App that collects key information regarding one customer from the ERP underlying database.

What I would like to achieve is that any email that is opened in Outlook gets a button with a hyperlink to that url and the email's sender address as the query string parameter.

How could this be done?

Comment: You could start by looking at the Microsoft Office Developer Tools to build a plugin.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try to see if this gives me a clue. Sounds pretty new and challenging to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop an Outlook add-in. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) to get started quickly.

You can add custom controls on the ribbon and add context menu items for contacts allowing users to make a call. VSTO provides two main ways for customizing the UI:

- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You may find the [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

If you need to support other platforms, not only the desktop edition of Outlook, you may consider developing a Mail App. See [Overview of mail add-ins for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161015%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). According to the latest news you will be able to add commands to the ribbon.